# Validation rule for record type is not working

Tags: apex, validation-rule, record-type

Below validation rule is not working. I want to check the record type contains R/O. If No only the user can edit the particular filed.

```
AND( 
NOT(CONTAINS($RecordType.Name , 'R/O')),
ISCHANGED( Please_explain_Additional_commitments__c ))
```

Is there any other ways to check the record type?

Comment: You should check `$RecordType.Label` rather than `$RecordType.Name`.

Comment: Record type contains R/O, What does it mean? whether it has a different name but it should contain R/o in that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "$RecordType.Name" use "RecordType.Name"

Comment: please refrain from asking the OP from marking as a best answer. Additionally, can you elaborate WHY the op has to use that syntax, just so they udnerstand, as well as others that might not be aware of why for completeness sake. thanks